# how to allow alphabetic input in jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

my question is how to allow the alphabetic input in jquery datepicker. I want to allow both the alphabetic input(it can be anything no restriction) and datepicker select option to be entered by user. thanks for any suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
$('#date').datepicker({
    constrainInput: false
});
```